# sou novo em java e esssa linha de código está dando erro

Tags: programação-funcional

import  javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null,"sla");
        System.exit(0);

```
}
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você colocou: ShowMessageDialog, com o 's' maiúsculo:

> Correto:

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sla");`

> Veja a imagem do código:

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Continua com o erro :(

Comment: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal teste

Comment: O nome da classe deve ser igual ao do nome do seu arquivo.

Comment: Tira um print da tela do seu editor e mande-a aqui, por favor.

Comment: Refaça o projeto, mas com os nomes corretos, a saber: nome da classe, nomes dos métodos. Aparentemente, o eclipse está procurando uma classe chamada 'este'.

Comment: ok kkkk eu me atrapalhei aqui, vou fazer isso